Why is spring not inserting value into ID column
I am trying to successfully map two classes in an OneToOne relationship; mainly because my User class needs two Ids that are GeneratedValue. I've used Lombok for getter setters and constructors ; I'm using postgres as database.
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private Long Id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
    @JoinColumn(name = "digital_code", referencedColumnName = "digital_code")  
    private DigitalCode digitalCode;  

    @Column (name = "name")  
    private String name;  
    @Column (name = "email")  
    private String email;
}

Second Class
@Entity public class DigitalCode {     
    @Id     
    @Column(name = "digital_code", unique = true, nullable = false)     
    @Size(min = 100000, max = 999999)     
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     
    private Long digitalCodeId; 
}

Both tables user and digital_code do get created in the database. However,
When I post data into my database with body
{     
    "name": "test name",     
    "email": "test@gmail.com", 
}

I get 200 back with
{   
    "digital_code": null,     
    "name": "test name",     
    "email": "test@gmail.com",     
    "id": 1
}

While I was expecting
{
    "digital_code": 100001, // due to @size annotation     
    "name": "test name",     
    "email": "test@gmail.com",     
    "id": 1
}


Could you show me how you're saving the user in your code?

could you show me the complete code like How you insert data?

@Kevin and Amar here's how I am saving the user:
userRepo.save(appointmentDetails)
Of course I am using DTOs to transform object, like the standard procedure.
The saving process works but it doesnt add a number to digital_code

Could you show me the complete code with which you save the user object, including the code you convert the user entity to the DTO ?

UserDto mapToUserDto(User user){
return new UserDto(
user.getId()
}

That's not how the @Size annotation works in JPA. The @Size annotation is a validation annotation, and it only gets called when your DTO is validated with @Valid or @Validated. It checks the value against the specified size during this validation process.
